# Minimizing realloc calls in a custom dynamically scaled array module

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I'm developing a custom dynamically scaled array module that aims to minimize the number of `realloc` calls while maintaining efficient memory usage. The module utilizes a strategy of doubling the allocated size when adding elements and decrease it to enough when removing elements. However, this approach leads to frequent `realloc` calls during element removal, as demonstrated in the following example:

| Allocated Size | Used Size | Removed Size | New Used Size | Enough Size | Realloc Called | Reallocated Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 18 | 2 | 16 | 32 | **No** | - |
| 32 | 16 | 1 | 15 | 30 | **Yes** | 30 |
| 30 | 15 | 1 | 14 | 28 | **Yes** | 28 |
| 28 | 14 | 1 | 13 | 26 | **Yes** | 26 |

As evident from the example, `realloc` is invoked almost every time an element is removed. To address this issue, I seek a strategy to minimize `realloc` calls while adhering to the policy of doubling the allocated size when adding elements and decrease it to enough when removing elements.

Code:

```c
#define DSA_USED_SIZE(dsa) ((dsa->length) * (dsa->elementSize))

typedef struct DSA
{
    void *data;
    size_t length;
    size_t allocatedSize;
    size_t elementSize;
} DSA;

// This is called before single or multiple items added.
int dsa_add_size_handle(DSA *dsa, size_t addSize)
{
    if (dsa->allocatedSize >= DSA_USED_SIZE(dsa) + addSize)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    size_t newSize = 2 * (DSA_USED_SIZE(dsa) + addSize);
    void *temp = realloc(dsa->data, newSize);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        perror("_dsa_add_size_handle: ");
        return 0;
    }
    dsa->data = temp;
    dsa->allocatedSize = newSize;
    return 1;
}

// This is called after single or multiple items removed.
int dsa_remove_size_handle(DSA *dsa, size_t removeSize)
{
    if (dsa->allocatedSize <= 2 * (DSA_USED_SIZE(dsa) - removeSize))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    size_t newSize = 2 * (DSA_USED_SIZE(dsa) - removeSize);
    if (newSize == 0)
    {
        newSize = 2 * dsa->elementSize;
    }
    void *temp = realloc(dsa->data, newSize);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        perror("_dsa_remove_size_handle: ");
        return 0;
    }
    dsa->data = temp;
    dsa->allocatedSize = newSize;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Usual `realloc()` implementations do not shrink used dynamic memory. You can ensure that `dsa->data` and `temp` are equal. Hence you should not warry about `realloc()` calls in `dsa_remove_size_handle()`, you even can omit `realloc()` call.

Comment: @273K But if it does not shrink, unused part of array won't be deallocated. Isn't that inefficient ?

Comment: @Ertugrul what do you mean by  `inefficient`?

Comment: Allocating a new memory and copying old data may be even more inefficient.

Comment: What is *"while maintaining efficient memory usage"*?

Comment: @273K So the heap of the process always increases? For example if I've a thousands of elements in array and if I remove all, the size of elements still allocated to process ?

Comment: "As evident from the example, realloc is invoked almost every time an element is removed" Nothing is evident from this example, except that there are four data points and in three of them realloc is invoked exactly as the code intends. Where these data points come from, why there are so few, and how they represent real use cases, are questions that this example doesn't answer.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It just an example to how my code works and to explain my problem better.

Comment: *If I remove all, the size of elements still allocated to process* It's an implementation detail. It's either `free()` or an error in `errno` or UB. RTFM.

Comment: I don't see any problem. You claim that there are "frequent realloc calls" but there is no actual data to base this claim on. There are some realloc calls. To say that they are frequent you need actual data from a bunch of real programs using your library.

Comment: If you have a struct like in this case and reduce the array size, you shouldn't deallocate memory. If the caller requests that the struct should get deleted entirely, that's when deallocation happens. The rationale for having the ever-increasing by x2 size is that data copying and realloc calls are so very expensive in terms of execution speed, that skipping it justifies occupying more memory overall. This is particularly true when dealing with tiny amounts < 256 bytes or so.